# Prove that we can choose the number $A$ such that the function $g$ definied on $[0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}]$ as

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Prove that we can choose the number $A$ such that the function $g$ definied on $[0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}]$ as following:
$$g(t)=\frac{1}{2} f(2t)-f(t)+\frac{1}{2} -A \frac{t^2}{2}$$ verifies the conditions of Rolle's theorem

I tried to apply condition of Rolle theorem on $g$ but i think that i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

$g(0)=0$ for all $A$, you have to prove there is an $A$ such that $g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})=0$

$f(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+\sqrt{1+\frac 1 3}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}}=\root^4\of 3$

$f(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3})=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}+\sqrt{1+\frac 4 3}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{3}}$

$1<f(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})<2$
$1<f(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3})<2$

$$\frac 1 2 -2+\frac 1 2- \frac A 6<g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})<\frac 1 22-1+\frac 1 2- \frac A 6$$
$$-1- \frac A 6<g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})<\frac 1 2- \frac A 6$$
So for $A=3 => g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})<0$ and for $A=-6 => g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})>0$ , Since g is continuous by A there is an $A\in(-6,3)$ such that $g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})=0$

Comment: I didn't really understand the solution for example why $1<f(...)<2$ and what you did in the last line

Comment: @user315918 ah sorry. $4<\sqrt{21}<5$ and $2<2\sqrt 3<4$ so $1<\sqrt 2<f(...)<\sqrt 3<2$

Answer (score 0):

You have to find $A$ such that $g(0)=g(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$